# AngularJS : throttle promise resolve/reject

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I would like ajax requests to take a minimum amount of time (e.g., 250ms).

Motive is to improves user experience: when the request starts a progress bar is displayed for the user and is removed when the request finishes. If the response completes is sub 100ms then the user experiences a blur of change on the screen and it looks janky.

My solution is to store the time the request started, and on response use $timeout to removes the progress indicator after "250ms minus response time".

However, this feels like a sub-optimal solution, and maybe even a problem that should not be solved in this way.

Is there a better pattern for solving this probem?

Comment: If this is a question about user experience, this is probably not the right site

Comment: I'd approach this in exactly the opposite way. Why punish users with fast connections by forcing them to wait longer just so they can see your progress bar? Why not have a timeout of 250ms before the progress bar displays?

Comment: While that question is about bluebird the problem and solution are essentially the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce a minimum delay by using `$q.all` and providing it two promises:

1. $http
2. $timeout

The behavior of `$q.all` is to wait until all the promises passed to it have been resolved before continuing with the `then` handler.

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($http, $timeout, $q) {
    var promise1 = $http({method:'GET', url:'api/users' });
    var promise2 = $timeout(function() {}, 250);
    $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(result) {
          // both promises resolved
    });
});
```